# Scrolling a big table

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-tables

With a big table that freezes the page.
Is making the table scrollable enough a solvable issue?

```
.scrollable {
    overflow-x:auto;
}
```

How can I solve the problem with Javascript and CSS as the table is created at the back end and included in the front end page?

Answer (score -1):

Even if the table is created in back-end. You have to make sure that only limited number of rows are created on front-end and when user scroll it to the end of the limited list. You can add more result at the end.

That way you won't face slowness and page freeze no matter how big records you have.